# MySql : Group rows my multiple columns and return the count

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table having the following structure:

```
ontology_term
pathway_id
pathway_name
```

I want to write a query using which we can get mapping between various pathways (having unique id's -> pathway_id) based on the number of common ontology terms.

So the output should be,

```
Pathway_id1, Pathway_id2, No. of common terms
```

I know, it can be easily done using a server side language, will it be faster to use MySql instead?

Comment: Can you provide some example data that relates to your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, that is

```
select a.pathway_id, b.pathway_id, count(*)
from t a
inner join t b on a.ontology_term = b.ontology_term
group by a.pathway_id, b.pathway_id
```

There is no record if two pathways do not have common terms

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, I added another condition "AND a.pw_id != b.pw_id" else it will also group each pathway by itself.